# Convert from dd/mm/yyyy to dd/mm in r

Tags: r

I have data spread over a period of two months. When I graph data points for each day, dates (dd/mm/yyyy) are overlapping and it is not possible to make sense of which date a certain point refers to. I tried to remove years from the date as they are not useful for the info I have and the dd/mm should leave enough space.

```
df$date<-as.Date(df$date, format="%d/%m")
```

However, it transforms the 01/09/2014 to 2015-09-01. I read that when the year is missing as.Date assumes current year and inputs it. Can I avoid this automatic insertion somehow?

Comment: Maybe reading `?format` could help

Comment: Thanks, will try it. Did not know about this function.

Comment: @Vasile for reference, `format` in the argument tells `R` how to interpret the string, not how to output it.

Comment: @Akhil thanks for the clarification. It is handy now as I am trying to make sense of the format function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this?

```
date <- as.Date("01/09/2014", format = %d/%m/%Y)
format(date, "%d/%m")
"01/09"
```

Comment: Almost but OP's input dates aren't in that format. Needs a `format` argument, i.e. `as.Date("01/09/2014", format = %d/%m/%Y)`